# Would it be useful to have a low-bandwidth version of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's hard to believe, but a significant number of [people still cling to dial-up internet.](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2013/08/21/3-of-americans-use-dial-up-at-home/) In certain rural areas, broadband [may not be available to users.](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/02/18/us/18broadband.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0)

[And accoding to a  study by Connected Nation](http://www.speedmatters.org/benefits/archive/rural_communities/) ,

> that 19 percent of rural residents say they do not subscribe to
>   broadband because it is not available in their area.

In order to make the bounty of  Stack Overflow  available to more people, might it be a good idea to have an old-school ASCII-only version of this site?

When I save the front-page of Stack, it registeres as 240K. With a speedy dial-up connection that would take about a minute(48 seconds at 5K/sec ).

I realize everyone here has broadband, but a *number* of potentially useful users do not.

Comment: Real programmers don't use dial-up. :P

Comment: Morse code via telegrams , nah homing pigeons

Comment: Aren't there a number of us broadband folks who might opt fo a lightning quick site though? sort of like Vim vs. Word

Comment: As long as they don't allow these pages to be indexed by Google. The most irritating thing in the world is searching for something and ending up on a text-only page that just shoves a wall of text in your face, then you find yourself screaming at your monitor, "Show me the full damn page!!!"

Comment: Once the scripts and stylesheets get cached, how much more low bandwidth would you expect?

Comment: @animuson - A *few* times, I've done the view-source trick when I just wanted to read embedded text

Comment: @MichaelT - Hmm, I can see your points.

Comment: I could see this being somewhat useful for parts of the world where high speed connections are less common or too expensive, but I'd like to see some supporting data

Comment: @apaul34208 - Like what types of supporting data?  Perhaps the number of dial-up users overseas ?  but I see the point, it would   good to have stats, true

Comment: @Coffee More like what percent of people world wide are stuck using dial up because they don't have other options.

Comment: @apaul34208 - Ok , understood

Answer (score 8):

You appear to be missing a number of existing speedups that already exist that make the question of low bandwidth a bit less of an issue.

Looking at what is actually transferred, the 224 KB front page that you see is sent compressed.  Html and English text compress very well - this amounted to only 36kb of data being sent.  Other parts aren't as compressible, but easily cacheable.

This is the results from a shift reload of the front page:

[image: A shift reload page]

And then after loading the page with things in cache, note all the 304s there.

[image: Cached reload]

The data that isn't cacheable on a front page load is about 40 kilobytes total of data transferred.  Trying to squeeze it beyond this may become an exercise in diminishing returns - the biggest bits are already sent compressed or get cached rapidly.

If you spoof as an iPhone (or have an iPhone), you do indeed get less stuff:

[image: A shift reload, spoofed as iphone]

Though after getting this cached,

[image: Cached iPhone front page]

we're looking at similar numbers, though instead of a 40kbish file, its a 20kbish file.  This partly reflects the fewer questions being served at a time.  If you are looking to compare a 40kb file download vs a 20kb file download... you too can spoof as a mobile device.

Comment: Does the mobile site consume even lesser bandwidth? Certain desktop browsers can load and render mobile sites (either when pointed to the mobile sub-domain or by changing user-agent string). It could be considered a "low-bandwidth" version.

Comment: @ADTC at the end of the day, once the resources are cached, its a 40kb file vs a 20kb after compression.  Though this could also be from the lack of functionality on the front page of a mobile device.  Though if you are worried about 40kb vs 20kb after stuff gets cached... we're going to need to talk about your bandwidth and [how low do you want to go](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Analogue_modem_-_acoustic_coupler.jpg).  At some point, its not that practical.

Comment: I understand what you mean; and thank you for expanding the post with iPhone spoof. What I meant to suggest is to promote the mobile site as a "low-bandwidth" version for those who *really* care that much about bandwidth. That way you can satisfy those who need one without actively creating one. All they need to do is spoof a mobile user-agent, as you just did for the iPhone spoof.